# Who are 313 main soldiers of Imam Mahdi?

Tags: shiism, imam-mahdi, soldier

It is a famous issue between Shiite that Imam Mahdi (as the last Imam of Shiite) has 313 soldiers. (Seemingly, as the main soldiers (commanders) of him). I wonder who they are?

***Note***: I do not mean who his common soldiers are, I mean who his main 313 soldiers or commanders are?

Answer (score 1):

There are many related issues regarding this matter, but apparently it has not mentioned what precisely their names are. But according to the traditions (hadiths), these individuals are similar to the 313 persons who were so gladiator and brave in Badr (بدر) war. On the whole, they have several specific characteristics such as:

- Ahl-al-Ikhlas (devotee)
- They are like lions (courageous, fearless)
- At nights say prayer, at day are fasting.
- And so on

As a related narration, Imam Mohammad al-Baqir (peace be upon him) said in regard to the tafseer (interpretation) of Surah Hud: 8 that:

> the purpose of Ummah-Ma’dudah is related to them (313 persons), I
>   swear in Allah that they will be gathered in an hour like … (Bahar al
>   Anwar Vol.52 page342)

---

**Reference:**

- [rasekhoon.net](http://rasekhoon.net/article/show/167163/313%20%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%20%DA%86%D9%87%20%DA%A9%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C%20%D9%87%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%86%D8%AF%D8%9F/)

Answer (score -3):

The 313 people. ..who they are i don't know. ..but I know that ....after the first fithna" almost 1000 people will join under a bridge with mahdi when enemies enter every home of Muslim. ..in the middle Friday Ramadan. .. (chance to 2020 see calander) even after the protection of the animal Rahila" these 1000 people reduced by kill or death leads to 313 and rise to work for black flag may be

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].

Comment: This does nothing to answer the actual question (see [answer]).